# Pytest failing to import third-party packages

Tags: python, django, pytest

So I am stuck with pytest. My setup is a django setup with docker-compose. Anytime I run pytest, I get errors like this

```
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
lib/python3.6/site-packages/compressor/tests/test_signals.py:4: in <module>
    from mock import Mock
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'
```

another one

```
 E   _pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: (local('/app/lib/python3.6/site-packages/testfixtures/tests/conftest.py'), (<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'sybil'"), <traceback object at 0x7fb8a7a4e780>))
```

Seems like it's having problem importing third-party libs, how do I ignore these kinds of errors.

Comment: you can't ignore this error, the test will fail if it relies on a 3rd party lib

Comment: the import looks like Python 2 (which needed an extra mock package, which is build-in in `unittest` in Python3). Could it be that you are running Python2 code under Python 3? Or did you just not install some packages?

Comment: This looks like an unusual setup you've got there; are you installing the tests inside the virtual env? Can you share your project layout?

Comment: sure, the project layout is exactly this https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django